# World Pay Integration with MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3, worldpay

Does anyone have any example code for integrating with WorldPay using MVC3? Specifically posting the XML order to WorldPay. I have googled all the way but couldnt find the relevant information .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WorldPay uses a pretty simple REST API.  Their developer documentation, which I think contains C# examples, should be all you need.

MVC doesn't change how you'd interact with them.  The code would be the same with a Silverlight or Windows Forms application.

Comment: A url would have been helpful